# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden - LinkedIn Share

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api

I am using following code to share post to LinkedIn using asp.net MVC.

```
public string Share(string linkedInResponseFromServer)
{
    JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(linkedInResponseFromServer);
    JToken accessCode = jobject["access_token"];

    string requestUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=" + accessCode;
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";            

    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        var shareMsg =
            new
            {
                comment =
                    "BIG Code is site where you can get code for sharing to various social sites. "
                    + "Currently, the site shows how you can use linkedIn OAuth2 related api usage. "
                    + "Add the site to your faviorite and keep checking for the updates.",
                content =
                    new
                    {
                        title = "BIG Code - Reference for Social Api code in C#",
                        submitted_url = "http://www.bigcode.net",
                        submitted_image_url =
                            "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-8r_lWT_32lQ/TxrQW12ngPI/AAAAAAAAI70/ifMF4Z16M-Y/s1600/SQL+Server+session+state.png",
                        description = string.Empty
                    },
                visibility = new { code = "anyone" }
            };

        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(shareMsg);
        stream.Write(json);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
    }

    WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return response;
}
```

But it gives following error from 
       WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse(); line.

Error is "Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

How can I solve this issue.

Comment: I think, after you call `request.GetRequestStream`the connection will close after you exit the using. Open the connection again after the using to see what happen.

Comment: Sorry.. I edited the question Error was "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

Comment: Is your `JToken accessCode`correct then, try to check this first.

Comment: JToken accessCode is correct. How to open the connection again.

Comment: Use the `Webrequest.Create(requestUrl)` again to open the connection. Right after the using.